# Need to change a file content type to text/plain so browsers don't prompt for a download and instead show it on the screen

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website hosted on a LiteSpeed server via the Hostinger platform.

I have a file called `stellar.toml` at [www.example.net/.well-known/stellar.toml](http://www.example.net/.well-known/stellar.toml). The WordPress file manager plugin tells me the file's kind is Plain text.

But if I type its URL I get a download started, I need instead to have the file's text prompted on the screen.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .htaccess on your `.well-known` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <FilesMatch "^stellar\.toml$">
    AddType text/plain .toml
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Something like this would work for NGINX too:

```
location ~* ^/stellar\.toml$ {
    default_type text/plain;
}
```

Comment: Isn't htaccess only for Apache?

Comment: @BenRacicot Updated with an NGINX version

Answer (score 0):

For apps hosted on Cloudflare Pages you can add a `_headers` file in your projects root which contains your rules.

```
/.well-known/*
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  content-type: text/plain
```

https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/headers/